# FamilyTree from sql

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I am trying to create a familytree program in Java from Database,  I have two classes:
  Node -  with getters and setter  etc.
  Main - connect to DB,and print the tree in console.
I have problem:
  -I only  built one level of my tree I do not know how to build the other levels

```
name   | father
-------+--------
moh    | adam 
Ali    | moh 
ammar  | moh 
maraw  | moh 
sabi   | ammar
```

```
         adam
          |
        moh
     /    |   \
maraw   ali   ammar
                |
               sabi
```

***Classe Node:***

```
public class Node {
            private String data;
            private Node parent;
            private List<Node> children;
```

***Classe Main:***

```
root = new Node("adam");

String SQL="select name from BB where father='"+root.getData()+"' ;
      ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
        while(rs.next())
        {
         child= new Node(rs.getString("name"));
        root.addChild(child);
     }
             Node.print(root);
```

Comment: Is using a relational database required? This would be a good job for NoSQL databases (i.e. GraphDBs, which can also represent trees). If you need to use a relational db you should search for how to represent hierarchical data.

Comment: i m using access...can u give code or sql requete like example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Please check below code

```
public void CreateTree()
{
        root = new Node("adam");
        AddChilds(root);
}


public void AddChilds(Node tree)
{
        String SQL="select name from BB where father='"+root.getData()+"' ;
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(SQL);
        while(rs.next())
        {
           Node child= new Node(rs.getString("name"));
           child.parent = tree;
           tree.addChild(child);//tree.children.Add(child);
        }
        tree.children.ForEach(X => { AddChilds(X); });
  }
```

Comment: thanck u.but print only the root("adam")

Comment: thank u alots ...ur code it works well..i have changed some error in my print method and  SQL. tree.getData()

Comment: Please do not concatenate values into SQL strings. Use a `PreparedStatement`